# Loading content on SharePoint 2010 intranet site

Tags: content-editor-web-part

Main problem is: You have to refresh the page a few time before all content in page opens! I have several web parts in the site like page viewer, Excel webpages etc.

Any ideas what might be the problem ?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem so that one can understand it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this issue is due to one of the bad web parts. In order to determine which one is bad. 1st you have to enable the developer dashboard. Follow [this blog to enable the Developer Dashboard](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/patrick_heyde/2009/11/16/sharepoint-2010-enable-using-developer-dashboard/)

With this you will which part of page is taking too much time to load. If it is web part either you can close it or remove from the page.

To close a web part, browser the site using this url `http://sitecolleciton url/default.aspx?contents=1` and close the web part. After that test the page load.

Comment: Can it be an delay-issue if the source-Excel(SP2007) that generates the data to webpart in SharePoint 2010 ?

Comment: it could be....you can test it simply closing that webpart using the link i mentioned above(putting ?content=1) and test it

Comment: Same issue when i closed the webpart